# How can a trigger be written so that it fires when a record is approved?

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process

Can a record change be detected so that a trigger will ONLY fire once a record has been approved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, triggers themselves can't be set to listen for a change on a specific field. Triggers can be set to fire on before/after insert, update, delete, and undelete events, and will always fire on every occurrence of their specified events.

The closest that you'll be able to get to that is to either use a workflow rule instead of a trigger, or perform a field update in the final approval steps of your approval process.

If you create a custom field on your object, say, `isApproved__c` (checkbox, default to false), your approval process could update that field when the final approval comes.

From there, you can wrap your desired trigger code in an `if(record.isApproved__c && !trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).isApproved__c)` block to prevent that specific code from being run until `isApproved__c` is flipped from false to true  (and you want to do the comparison against the old value as well, lest your code execute on every single trigger firing after it is approved).

+edit:

Now that I think about it a little more, I believe that a field update in the final approval steps is required no matter which route you take.

It's hard to know for sure (without further clarification) if a workflow rule would be able to accomplish what you're looking to do. However, if you can accomplish your ultimate goal with a workflow rule, it's generally preferred to go with a workflow rule over a trigger (clicks over code mentality).

Answer (score 5):

The approval process cannot directly trigger the apex trigger.

You will need to create a field (e.g. checkbox) that is checked by the approval step in the approval process. Then start a trigger based on that field.

Don't forget to reset the checkbox field when the trigger completes. This can be done by the trigger.

Comment: or, simply have the field update be setting an 'approval_status__c` field to `Approved` - then no clearing required (however, must be cleared on clone!)